# Maven recursive dependency exclusion

Tags: java, maven, junit

Let's say I am developing project A that depends on project B and JUnit-11.

```
A -> junit-11 and B
```

Project B depends on project C and JUnit-8. but it is already packaged and I have no control over modifying its content.

```
B -> junit-8  and C
```

Project C has dependency on jUnit-8 as well.

```
C -> junit-8
```

Now, the problem is when I try build my project (project A), it also gets jUnit-8 which breaks the compilation. I can exclude the dependency of project B on jUnit-8 when defining that in my pom.xml but that does not propagates to the dependency of project C. As a result, jUnit-8 is still downloaded and breaks my project.

here are the related pom.xml:

```
Project A (My Project) :pom.xml:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>B</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>       
        </exclusion>

    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Project B (Existing project):pom.xml:
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>C</groupId>
            <artifactId>C</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

Project C (Existing project):pom.xml:
<dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any advice on how to define a recursive exclusion that excludes jUnit-8 in all sub-dependencies?

Comment: It's unusual to have junit dependencies declared that are not in `<scope>test</scope>`.

Comment: well, they are declared with test scope but I removed that here to simplify. Besides, there is similar issue with some other dependencies that are not limited to test scope as well.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use [Dependency Management](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) in your pom.xml

Comment: You may want to highlight specific feature of dependency management which allows exclusions.